# C# Method overloading and generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I'm confused by a problem we have in our project. I tried to simplify it to reproduce the effect:

```
interface IBar { }

class Bar : IBar {}

interface IFoo<T> where T : IBar { }

class Foo<T> : IFoo<T> where T : IBar { }


class Class1
{
    public void DoTheFoo<T>(T bar) where T : IBar
    {}

    public void DoTheFoo<T>(IFoo<T> foo) where T : IBar
    {}


    public void Test()
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        var foo = new Foo<Bar>();

        DoTheFoo(bar); // works

        DoTheFoo<Bar>(foo); // works
        DoTheFoo((IFoo<Bar>)foo); // works
        DoTheFoo(foo); // complains
    }
}
```

To me this looks fine, but the compiler complains on the last call, because it tries to `DoTheFoo<T>(T bar)`, instead of `DoTheFoo<T>(IFoo<T> foo)` and complains that the argument type does not fit.

- When I remove the method `DoTheFoo<T>(T bar)`, the last call works!
- When I change it to `DoTheFoo<T>(Foo<T> foo)`, it works, but I can't use that

It is not too hard to work around this in our current code. But it is a) strange and b) too bad that we can't have these two overloaded methods.

Is there a common rule that explains this behaviour? Is it possible to make it work (except of giving the methods different names)?

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate. There is the problem that the methods are different in the generic constraints. My methods are different in the declared argument type.

Comment: No, that's a duplicate. Read my answer carefully. It explains why overload resolution picks the method it does in your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a matter of type inference not quite working in your favour when combined with overload resolution. It's easy to fix by just specifying the type argument explicitly - no cast is required:

```
DoTheFoo<Bar>(foo);
```

Usually I'm nervous of overloads which take fairly different parameter types though. Often the code ends up simpler if you just give the methods different names. Aside from anything else, then your *readers* don't need to try to perform overload resolution at the same time as type inference...

EDIT: I believe the problem is that the ordering works like this:

- Both methods are found
- Type inference is applied to both methods *without validating the constraints* - so for the first method, we get `T = Foo<Bar>` and for the second method we get `T = Bar`. Both methods are applicable at this point.
- Overload resolution is performed, which decides that the first method is the most specific one.
- Only *after* overload resolution has been performed is the constraint on `T` checked - and that fails because there's no reference conversion from `Bar` to `IFoo`.

There's an [Eric Lippert blog post about why the language is designed this way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx), a [blog post I wrote about it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints.aspx), and [an article I wrote about overloading in general](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx). Each of them may or may not help :)

EDIT: Leaving type inference aside for a moment, the reason the first method is more specific is that in one case we're converting from `Foo<Bar>` to `Foo<Bar>`, and in the other we're converting from `Foo<Bar>` to `IFoo<Bar>`. As per section 7.5.3.3 of the C# 5 specification:

> Given an implicit conversion C1 that converts from an expression E to a type T1, and an implicit conversion C2 that converts from an expression E to a type T2, C1 is a better conversion than C2 if at least one of the following holds:
>   - E has a type S and an identity conversion exists from S to T1 but not from S to T2
>   - ...

The identity conversion is from a type to itself, which *is* the case for the first overload, but *isn't* for the second. So the first conversion is better.

Comment: I'm not so sure that it is because of the type inference. Consider that it does not complain that the type can't be told by the arguments. It also works, when the first DoTheFoo method is removed...

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: Type inference is failing *in the face of overloading*. The whole thing is really tricky - try following it all in the specification - but clearly type inference is *part* of the problem, otherwise it wouldn't work when you specify the type argument explicitly, surely.

Comment: That's actually the strangest part of this case. When I specify the generic argument, it works. Although it is capable of finding it, at least when the first overload is removed.

Comment: I think it must be a problem in which order the compiler tries to find the correct overload. It seems to prefer the one with the generic argument to the one with the more specific type. (`IFoo<T>` seems to be more specific than `T` to me). This is strange.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: That's my point exactly: type inference and overload resolution interact in ways which are sometimes confusing. It really is worth trying to work through the specification and see what's going on, if only to get a feel for how labyrinthine it can be. Again, removing the overloading (by giving the methods different names) would make this significantly simpler both in terms of the compiler *and* anyone reading the code. I suspect that what's happening is that type inference is occurring, then overload resolution, *then* constraint validation.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: See my edit for a justification. Will address the "more specific part" in a second.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: Whether `IFoo<T>` is more or less specific than `T` is not the relevant question. Method type inference *succeeds*, and then after it succeeds the question is "which is the better *conversion*: `foo` converted to `IFoo<Bar>` via *reference* conversion or `foo` converted to `Foo<Bar>` via *identity* conversion? Clearly the identity conversion wins, so overload resolution picks as its best method the `Foo<Bar>` method. Only then are constraints checked, and we determine that `Foo<Bar>` does not meet the `IBar` constraint.